# Unconstrained integer quadratic optimization

Tags: optimization, quadratics, discrete-optimization

Assuming a single variable quadratic optimization problem:

$(\alpha x + \beta)^2$

where

$x \in Z$

the optimal value can be found by relaxing the integer requirement and then rounding to the nearest integer number. Can we do a similar trick if we have 2 integer variables in a quadratic function, or that is NP-hard?

Comment: You don't even mention whether you're maximizing or minimizing.