# Unconstrained integer quadratic programming

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

What are the approaches for finding the global optimum of an unconstrained quadratic optimization problem where all variables are integers? When the integrality constraint is relaxed, the problem is convex. The variables can be binary as well.

Comment: There isn't a fixed method, because its an open problem...

Comment: Is your quadratic objective (ignoring the integrality constraint) convex or non-convex?

Comment: Are you interested in heuristics or exact algorithms?

Comment: Are your integer variables all binary?

Comment: The quadratic function is convex. The variables are integer, but binaries might also work. Looking for all sorts of algorithms, including heuristics.

Comment: [Lattice problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4059150/339790)

Comment: The standard approach is to use an off-the-shelf Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming (MIQP) solver, of which there are many for many different popular computing environments..

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to understand how do these solvers find the optimal solution. Let's say I have least-squares mixed-integer programming. How do I calculate the optimum solution? I could not find anything in Stephen Boyd's book.

Comment: @dsp_guy2020 Google "lattice cryptography". Hassibi wrote about it: https://ee.caltech.edu/Babak/pubs/sphere.html

Answer (score 2):

For unconstrained integer convex optimization, you can solve the continuous relaxation by any method, and an integer optimal solution is obtained by rounding each component up or down.  Explicitly, if the continuous optimal solution is $(x_1^*, \dots,x_n^*)$, an integer optimal solution is among the $$\prod_{j=1}^n (\lceil x_j^* \rceil - \lfloor x_j^* \rfloor + 1)\le 2^n$$ points of the form $(y_1^*, \dots, y_n^*)$, where $y_j^* \in \{\lfloor x_j^* \rfloor, \lceil x_j^* \rceil\}$.

Comment: There's a pretty good chance that the number of candidate solutions will be close to if not equal to $2^n$, so you likely will want to use a branch-and-bound approach rather than full enumeration.